# how to change "HTML" style

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to change style of html element

```
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("html");
document.body.style.height = height + "px";
document.body.style.width = width + "px";
x.style.height = height + "px";
x.style.width = width + "px";
```

`body.style` is working but I want to change html style also 
It gives an error

> Cannot read property style of undefined

Comment: `var x = document.querySelector("html");` getElementsByTagName returns a collection so you need to index to the first item

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array element. Try to use `x[0]` to get the `html` element.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("html");
x[0].style.height = "1000px";
```

Comment: You have enough rep to find and vote for an obvious dupe of a typo-type question